# Issue on Setting Highcharts Spider Web Legend in One Iine at button of Chart

Tags: highcharts

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/) and let me know how I can enable highcharts to put the legend items in one line and at buttom of the chart?

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
                
        chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'line'
        },
        
        title: {
            text: 'Budget vs spending',
            x: -80
        },
        
        pane: {
            size: '80%'
        },
        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support', 
                    'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0
        },
            
        yAxis: {
            gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0
        },
        
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
        },
        
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 70,
            layout: 'vertical'
        },
        
        series: [{
            name: 'Allocated Budget',
            data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }, {
            name: 'Actual Spending',
            data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]
    
    });
});
```

As you can see the position of the legend is the right and it is in two line now.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want this:

```
legend: {
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            layout: 'horizontal'
        }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/pxS6X/